# how to create a service to restart other service if dead?

Tags: android, android-service

If there a way (and good practices) for the creation of a second service to supervise if the main app service is running or killed by the system and to restart it?

Comment: Maybe there is problem to check if the second service is killed :/

Comment: If the first service uses `START_STICKY`, it will be restarted by the system automatically -- you do not need a second service for that. Besides, on Android 8.0+, you will need to use a foreground service, and a process with a foreground service is rarely killed by the system to free up memory.